# Want to add rows to new table using jstl for loop and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jstl

I have two tables on my jsp page, the first one is dynamically created using a list from a java servlet. Every row of this table has an add button that is used to add the row clicked to secondary table.
I am using jstl to generate the first table and a JQuery code to create the onClick function of every button in the table.
That's my JSP code:

```html
<table style="text-align: left; width: 732px;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 288px;">Nombre<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 201px;">Tipo<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 93px;">Precio<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 50px">Cantidad<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 56px;">Añadir<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <c:forEach var ="tempPan" items= "${sessionScope.CATALOGO}" varStatus="loop">
     <!-- Link para cada compra con su campo clave -->
  <c:url var="linkAnyadir" value="VerCompras">
   <c:param name="id" value="${tempPan.id}"></c:param>
  </c:url>
   <tr>
        <td id="nombre${loop.index}" style="vertical-align: top; width: 288px;">${tempPan.nombre}<br>
        </td>
        <td id="tipo${loop.index}" style="vertical-align: top; width: 201px;">${tempPan.tipo}<br>
        </td>
        <td id="precio${loop.index}" style="vertical-align: top; width: 93px;">${tempPan.precio}<br>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 50px"><input id="cantidad${loop.index}" name="tCantidad"><br>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 56px;"><button type="button" id="add${tempPan.id}">Agregar</button><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
   <script type="text/JavaScript">
    
    $("#add"+'${loop.index}').on("click", function(){
     $('#test > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+$("#nombre"+'${loop.index}').val()+'</td><td>'+$("#tipo"+'${loop.index}').val()+'</td><td>'+$("#cantidad"+'${loop.index}').val()+'</td><td>'+$("#precio"+'${loop.index}').val()+'</td></tr>');
    });
 </script>
 </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<h4>Carrito:</h4>
<br>
<table id="test" style="text-align: left; width: 471px;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 103px;">Nombre<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 57px;">Tipo<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 163px;">Cantidad<br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 114px;">Precio<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My code generates the first table correctly but, when I press the add button, adds a void row to the second table like:

[Result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNErZ.png)

I think the problem is there on some html or javascript trying to get jstl variable like id="nombre${loop.index}", or $("#nombre"+'${loop.index}').val()

Any help please?

Comment: Maybe you should check the HTML rendered from the JSP template or check for any error message in the console of browser.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem, I was using .val() instead of .html() on append jquery method. It works like:

```js
$("#add"+'${loop.index}').on("click", function(){
     $('#test > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+$("#nombre"+'${loop.index}').html()+'</td><td>'+$("#tipo"+'${loop.index}').html()+'</td><td>'+$("#cantidad"+'${loop.index}').val()+'</td><td>'+$("#precio"+'${loop.index}').html()+'</td></tr>');
    });
```